# Rails checkbox and label on same line

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

anyone know how to get a checkbox and label to line up?

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <div class="field form-group">
      <%= ff.label :cert_never_expires, 'This certification does not expire' %>
      <%= ff.check_box :cert_never_expires, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>        
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Please post the CSS for `field form-group` and `form-control`

Comment: no CSS yet.  couldn't get anything to work that i was trying.  Those are just Bootstrap ones that are in there now.

Comment: you can modify it by using css.  or you can examples here http://bootsnipp.com/

Comment: Are your using bootstrap css ?

Comment: yes I'm using bootstrap css

Answer (score -1):

Do you really need to use that div , i mean if it is not required then remove it otherwise

```
<td style="width: 30%">
   <div class="field form-group">
   <%= ff.label :cert_never_expires, 'This certification does not expire' %>
   <%= ff.check_box :cert_never_expires, class: "form-control" %>
   </div>
 </td>
```

Comment: Using inline 'style' is a bad practice, use CSS to style your elements.

Answer (score -1):

Got it working

```
<div>
  <%= ff.label :cert_never_expires, "This certification does not expire", class: "l" %>
  <%= ff.check_box :cert_never_expires, class: 'cb' %>
</div>
```

here's the CSS

```
  .cb {
    text-align: center;    
    width: 5%;
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }  

 .l {
     padding-right: 5px;
 }
```